# How to efficiently select aggregate SUM value from an INNER JOINed table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a child table with a status column. When I select columns from a parent table I'd like to also report a computed status based on all related rows in a child table. The computation of the status is very simple: if all statuses in related child table rows are 0 then the status in the query will be set to 0. Otherwise, the status will be set to a non-zero value (not really important what the actual value is).

My implementation of a query (as seen below) uses SUM() on related child rows. This approach works fine. However, because of the SUM() I need to GROUP BY all columns selected from two other tables.

Is there a better way to do that? Should I worry about the performance when grouping by so many columns?

Btw, keys, indexes, and relations have been omitted from the sample.

Sample tables and a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test
GO

USE [Test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer]
(
    [CustomerId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
    [OrderId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description1] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Description2] [nvarchar](26) NOT NULL,
    [Description3] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [RecommendedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].OrderItem
(
    [OrderId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSelectInvoiceSubmissionRecords]
    @CustomerId bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        c.Name
        , c.PhoneNumber
        , o.OrderId
        , o.Description1
        , o.Description2
        , o.Description3
        , o.[Date]
        , o.Amount
        , o.[RecommendedBy]
        , SUM(i.Status) AS [ItemStatus]
    FROM [Order] o
    INNER JOIN OrderItem i ON i.OrderId = o.OrderId
    INNER JOIN [Customer] c ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
    WHERE o.CustomerId = @CustomerId
    GROUP BY c.Name, c.PhoneNumber, o.OrderId, o.Description1, o.Description2, o.Description3, o.Date, o.Amount, o.RecommendedBy;
END
```

Comment: Do not try to prematurely optimize. Some considerations - will this query be executed frequently (as is and without further filtering)? Somehow I suspect it is not. But this has a smell to it. Typically in an order processing system orders "age" out of general (or daily) consideration when they are "closed" (or "shipped" or whatever terminology your org uses). Is that what you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find that using a correlated subquery provides better performance:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.PhoneNumber, o.OrderId, o.Description1, o.Description2, o.Description3,
       o.[Date], o.Amount, o.[RecommendedBy]
       (SELECT SUM(i.Status)
        FROM OrderItem i
        WHERE i.OrderId = o.OrderId
       ) AS [ItemStatus]
FROM [Order] o JOIN
     [Customer] c
     ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId     
WHERE o.CustomerId = @CustomerId;
```

With such a small amount of data (a single customer) this might not have a big impact on performance, but the query is easier to maintain.

Comment: You could use max instead of sum if the only consideration is whether status is zero or not zero.

Comment: @SMor Very good suggestion. Having one of the actual item statuses might help during troubleshooting if needed.